# I am new react, I want to create person list, where you can add a name and number for people, but I am stuck

Tags: reactjs

What I want is that, whenever user try to add new person (name, number) the program will first check if the that name exist, if it does, it will alert the user that the name is already exist and if you want to replace. For now the program is working if the user doesn't exist, but if it does exist the program fails. I really don't know how to get that done after all the search here and google. Thanks for your help.

Here is my code:

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Person from './components/Person';
import personDetails from './services/person';

const App = (props) => {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('')

    const { name, number } = props;
    
    const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]);
    const [input, setInput] = useState({
      name: "",
      number: ""
    });
    
    useEffect(() => {
      personDetails
        .allPersons()
        .then(response => {
          setPersons(response.data)
        })
    }, [])

    const [ newName ] = useState('')
  
    const addPerson = input => {      

      setPersons([...persons, { name: input.name, number: input.number }]);
      setInput({ name: "", number: "" });

      personDetails
        .createPerson(input)
        .then(response => {
          setPersons(persons.concat(response.data))
        })
    };

    const handleSubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      persons.forEach(function(s, p) {
        if(s.name !== input.name) {
          addPerson(input);
        } else {
          window.alert(`${s.name} is already in the phonebook, replace the old number with a new one?`)
          personDetails
          .editPerson(s.id)
          .then(response => {
            persons.filter(person => {
              if(person.name !== "" && person.number !== "") {
                return person
              }
            })
          })
        }
      })
    };

    const handleChange = e => {
      setInput({
        ...input,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      });
    };
    const filteredPeople = persons.filter(person => {
      return person.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    })
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Phonebook</h2>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
          <div>filter shown with</div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)} />
          
        </div>
        <h2>add a new</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            name: 
            <input
              name="name"
              type="text"
              value={name}
              onChange={handleChange}
            /><br />
            number: 
            <input
              name="number"
              type="text"
              value={number}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="submit">add</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <h2>Numbers</h2>
        <li>
          {filteredPeople.map(person => 
            <Person handleChange={handleChange} 
                    handleSubmit={handleSubmit} 
                    addPerson={addPerson} 
                    input={props} key={person.number} 
                    person={person}             
            />
            )}
        </li><br />
      </div>
    )
  }

export default App;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
  
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

person.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/persons'

const allPersons = () => {
    return axios.get(baseUrl)
}

const createPerson = input => {
    return axios.post(baseUrl, input)
}

const deletePerson = (id, persons) => {
    return axios.delete(`${baseUrl}/${0}`, persons)
}

const editPerson = (id, persons) => {
    return axios.put(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, persons)
}

export default { allPersons, createPerson, deletePerson, editPerson }
```

db.json

```
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "name": "Mary Poppendieck",
      "number": "39-23-6423122",
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "Dan Abramov",
      "number": "1234",
      "id": 13
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have the code for the person service?

Comment: That's is the person.js file

Comment: I meant the Person component. :)

Comment: import React from 'react';
import deleteOne from '../services/person';

const Person = ({id, person}) => {
    const handledelete = () => {
        alert(`Delete ${person.name}?, ${person.name} will disappear when you refresh`)
        deleteOne
            .deletePerson(person.id)
           
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {person.name} {person.number} 
            <button onClick={handledelete}>delete</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Person

Comment: Ok let me try moving the code to the person.js file.

Comment: your `editPerson(id, persons)` should recieve **two** arguments as stated in `person.js`. But in your `handleSubmit`, you just send `editPerson(s.id)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have put together a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-hypatia-fgd24?file=/src/App.js) of what I *think* you are trying to do.  I substituted out your `axios` calls with dummy Promises using your presented data as a base.  There were a number of changes that had to go in to make this work.  Take a look and let me know if you have questions.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Person from "./components/Person";
import personDetails from "./services/person";

const App = ({ name, number }) => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState({ name, number });
  console.log("input", input);

  useEffect(() => {
    personDetails.allPersons().then((response) => setPersons(response.data));
  }, []);

  const addPerson = (input) => {
    personDetails.createPerson(input).then((response) => {
      setInput((prev) => ({ name: "", number: "" }));
      setPersons((prev) => [...prev, response.data]);
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const existingPerson = persons.find((_) => _.name === input.name);
    if (existingPerson) {
      if (
        window.confirm(
          `${existingPerson.name} is already in the phonebook, replace the old number with a new one?`
        )
      ) {
        personDetails.editPerson(existingPerson.id, input).then((response) => {
          setPersons((prev) => [
            ...prev.filter((_) => _.id !== response.id),
            response
          ]);
        });
      }
    } else {
      addPerson(input);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInput((prev) => ({
      ...input,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
  };
  const filteredPeople = persons.filter((person) => {
    return person.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <div>filter shown with</div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search..."
          onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <h2>add a new</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          name:
          <input
            name="name"
            type="text"
            value={input.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <br />
          number:
          <input
            name="number"
            type="text"
            value={input.number}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      <li>
        {filteredPeople.map((person) => (
          <Person
            handleChange={handleChange}
            handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
            addPerson={addPerson}
            key={person.number}
            person={person}
          />
        ))}
      </li>
      <br />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Yeah this still work exactly as my own did. it does add to the list instead of replacing the old one

Comment: What I want is to replace the old number with the new associated name

Comment: Okay, in your code you were comparing names during your lookup.  It appeared you wanted to replace the id if the names matched.  I have updated the example to compare ids and replace the name instead.  https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-poincare-fzq5z